# How to integrate backbone.sync with jstorage?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm a newbie javascript developer (first post here!) and been recently trying to play with backbone.sync. I've been reading through the [todo](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) example and notice that it uses [backbone-localstorage](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html). My feeling is that backbone-localstorage was just a quick implementation that the author used for demo purposes. I also noticed that the keys are randomly generated, whereas I would like something that would allow me to name my own key values.

I've been looking at jstorage (www.jstorage.info), and would really appreciate some pointers (preferably with code samples) on how to integrate it with backbone.js. I imagine **backbone.sync** would need to be overriden somehow as is done in backbone-localstorage.

Alternatively, what localStorage plugin/wrapper would you recommend, and how would it integrate with backbone?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My feeling is that backbone-localstorage was just a quick implementation that the author used for demo purposes.

Exactly right. I'd say that the implementation is fine for most things, but what support you can get for it is probably minimal.

> I also noticed that the keys are randomly generated, whereas I would like something that would allow me to name my own key values.

This isn't really correct.  I assume you are referring to this:

```
// Add a model, giving it a (hopefully)-unique GUID, if it doesn't already
// have an id of it's own.
create: function(model) {
    if (!model.id) model.id = model.attributes.id = guid();
    this.data[model.id] = model;
   this.save();
   return model;
}
```

Here, what's happening is that when a create is called on a model, it tries to determine if an `id` has been set on the model, and if no such `id` is provided, then the `guid` function is used to build one.  This isn't setting a key randomly, it's fulfilling the requirement that every saved model should have an id (by assigining a random one).

Modifying the `backbone-localstorage.js` code should be fairly trivial.  Let's look at the store constructor as an example

```
Before:
var Store = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    var store = localStorage.getItem(this.name);
    this.data = (store && JSON.parse(store)) || {};
};
```

The only thing we need to update here is the call to localStorage:

```
After:
var Store = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    //Notice here, that jStorage gives us the option to define a default.
    var store = $.jStorage.get(this.name, {}); 
    this.data = store;
};
```

Similarly simple is the save function:

```
Before:
save: function() {
    localStorage.setItem(this.name, JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

again, simply update the call to localStorage:

```
After:
save: function() {
    $.jStorage.set(this.name, this.data);
}
```

**Update**: jStorage handles all the JSON.stringify, and JSON.parse for you, so I've updated the above code to reflect that.

Easy peasy, right!

Anyways, this is a great exercise, and I wish you the best of luck.  I hope that I've been able to help you out.

P.s. One thing that bothers me about the localStorage plugin is that it uses `model.attributes.xxx`, where it's better to use `model.get("xxx")`.  This way, if they ever change the internals of model change, your code won't break.

P.p.s. as far as how to generate guids, and weather a random guid is appropriate for you, depends upon your domain.  With the TODO example, there is no backing database to sync with, so any old guid would do the trick, but in many other cases, you may be using html5 storage to create an offline version of your app, so id's need to be compatable with the db.  In these cases, using a random guid is probably not that great an idea, but the one provided by the backbone-localstorage plugin is designed so that it isn't likely to collide with your db's actual id's, so it's not _*that bad*.  There isn't really a right answer here, so do what makes sense for your domain.

Comment: Upvoting you because you bothered to write some code whereas I didn't feel like it. :)  Also, sometimes I write methods that hide even the model.get('xxx') because this even implies too much knowledge of the internals.  If the model ever changes its underlying attributes, you have the same problem, basically.

Comment: It seems much less likely that they would change `.get`, and you can go too far down the rabbithole of wrapping too much quite easily.  Using `.get` seems the appropriate level.

Comment: I think I would agree to disagree with you on that.  There is really no difference between model.attributes.xxx and model.get('xxx').  In both cases, the caller knows too much about the underlying implementation.  That said, its probably harmless in this context.

Comment: @idbentley Thanks a lot for the code. I'm getting an error on this line 'this.data = (store && JSON.parse(store));' _SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL_. Any ideas? Also, I notice we didn't override Backbone.sync as I previously thought was necessary, but instead modified the 2 functions that you mentioned. Does that imply that backbone-localstorage.js itself is required for jstorage? I previously thought the way to do it was to add a Backbone.sync method to jstorage.js.

Comment: Also, for the GUID generation, is it standard practice to implement it the way done in backbone-localstorage? (That is, 4 random hex digits). Why not incremental values? Thanks a lot both @Bill and @idbentley for your patience and answering my questions.

Comment: @fortuneRice Sorry, I didn't test the code, it turns out that jStorage and localStorage differ slightly on this.  I've updated my answer to reflect the correct usage of jStorage.  As far as having to override Backbone.sync, you still have to.  What I was trying to say is that modifying the backbone localstorage code to use jStorage is very simple - You'll have to create a new plugin called backbone-jstorage.js, and update it so that it uses only jStorage code.  Does this make sense?  I'll add some notes about GUID generation to my answer as well.

Comment: @idbentley Thanks the updated snippets work and explanation is clear! You made my first ever question on StackOverflow a positive experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look first at the local storage plugin that backbone.js provides.  There are plenty of code samples that should give you an idea of how you would swap in jstorage as the underlying storage mechanism.  See it here:

[backbone-localstorage.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html)

Comment: Yes I had taken a look at that example and saw that backbone.sync needs to be overridden somehow. Is there a standard adapter for jstorage, or has anyone tackled this before and can provide the code?

Comment: I don't see any ready-to-use implementations out there.  But it seems easy enough to take what they've done with their plugin and start swapping in jstorage calls in the API methods.  Basically, everywhere where you see them accessing their data property, you need to use equivalent jstorage calls.  Make sense?